# flutter_map zooming and pannig is freezing

Tags: flutter, web, maps

I'm developing a flutter web application using https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map, to load some shapes in geojson format. Everything is fine when the user zooms in or out, but when trying to pan the map (panning behavior), it doesn't seem to move until I zoom again.

Any helps?
Thanks.